# Dynamically loading dependency in maven

Tags: dynamic, dependencies, maven-3

Can we dynamically load dependencies using maven.

For example, lets say we have a web project which needs a specific jar A to run on Glassfish server, while the same project needs additional jar B to run on weblogic in its WEB-INF/lib folder.

Do I need to have the separate pom.xml file for glassfish and weblogic and then run the appropriate pom.xml depending on the server being used?

Or Can I have a single pom.xml with both dependencies i.e. both jar A and jar B specified in it and depending on the parameters passed to pom.xml while running it (like mvn clean package -Dserver=glassfish),  it will load the jar A only?

Is this possible?

What is the most appropriate way of doing this?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exploit the concept of profiles in maven. You can create a whole profile of your execution environment and launch maven with that profile. For more info, see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

These profiles can be defined within pom or can be defined in an external file and refer it to in pom. You can activate a profile by launching it with -P option, mvn  -P

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can we have some common dependencies in pom and then profile specific dependency in each profile. So, generated war file will have common dependencies as well as the dependencies specified in the currently executing profiles?

Comment: Yeah! If that suits you. Either way should be fine, though I'm not sure what the best practice is. Profiles have a wider application range than to be used just for dependencies. For instance, you don't need to generate javadoc for every nightly build. So, create a profile to generate javadoc and use this only for releases.